# Pygame's music.load says "No such file or directory" even though file exists and is playable

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `pygame.mixer.music.load` to load an audio file and play it. However, even though the file exists and is playable, I'm still getting a "No such file or directory" error.

Here is the snippet of code:

```py
import os
import pygame
import tempfile
from pydub import AudioSegment

tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".mp3", delete=False)
bgm = AudioSegment.from_mp3(r"C:\Users\creep\sound.mp3")
bgm = bgm + 10
bgm.export(tmp_file.name, format='mp3')

print(f"{os.path.exists(tmp_file.name)=}")

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(tmp_file.name)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

```
> python .\test_so.py
pygame 2.5.1 (SDL 2.28.2, Python 3.11.4)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
os.path.exists(tmp_file.name)=True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\creep\work\test_so.py", line 15, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load(tmp_file.name)
pygame.error: No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\creep\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbux7qvnu.mp3'.
```

```
>>> import pygame
pygame 2.5.1 (SDL 2.28.2, Python 3.11.4)
```

Double-checked that the file exists in two different directories:

- C:\Users\creep\sound.mp3
- C:\Users\creep\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbux7qvnu.mp3

Additional Information

Interestingly, when I run the following code snippet, the audio file plays successfully:

```py
import pygame
import time

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\Users\creep\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbux7qvnu.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: `NamedTemporaryFile` creates a new random name each time you run the program.  Are you sure this is ALL of your code?  My guess is there's more going on here.

Comment: Actually, this is not all of it, but it is the minimum code that will reproduce the problem I encountered.
Also, the name of this temporary file changes every time, so I check the files I check accordingly.

Comment: But why does the error say "<stdin> line 1"?  Are you running this from inside an IDE?

Comment: The error says `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`.  But in the posted code, line 1 is `import pygame`.  It's very hard to help when you don't share your real code.

Comment: You are certainly right. I used interactive python to create the minimal code to ask the question, hence the error.
I have now fixed it and if you would like to take a look at it.

Comment: Try `tmp_file.close()` before trying to play it? Maybe the open file handle is breaking things.

Comment: @Random Davis
Thanks, you are right, by closing the tmp_file before calling music.load(), the music played.
Is it because the file was locked by tempfile?

Comment: Keeping a file open necessarily keeps that file "locked"; until you specify you are done writing to the file by closing it, you are essentially telling the operating system "I'm still in the middle of writing/reading this, so nobody can touch it!"